# how can I copy the audit log to log server?

Tags: centos7, rsyslog

I want to copy the audit file to log server, (CentOS 7)

When I put in /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
audit.* @logserver:514
```

I get the error:

> rsyslogd: unknown facility name "audit" [v8.24.0-41.el7_7.2]

When I trying to copy the audit log, as I do with apache log, I put:

```
$ModLoad        imfile
$InputFileName /var/log/audit/audit.log
$InputFileTag tag_audit_log:
$InputFileStateFile audit_log
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputRunFileMonitor
if $syslogtag == 'tag_audit_log'   then @logserver:514
```

I get the error:

> rsyslogd: imfile: on startup file '/var/log/audit/audit.log' does not
>   exist but is configured in static file monitor - this may indicate a
>   misconfiguration. If the file appears at a later time, it will
>   automatically be processed. Reason: Permission denied
>   [v8.24.0-41.el7_7.2]

The file exist:

```
# ls -lZ /var/log/audit/audit.log
-rw-------. root root system_u:object_r:auditd_log_t:s0 /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

How to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, I [follow](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/28676):

In /etc/syslog.conf I put

```
*.info        @remote.syslog.example.com
```

In /etc/audisp/plugins.d/syslog.conf:

```
active = yes
```

> systemctl restart rsyslog
>   service auditd restart